# How to get exact match keyword from the given string using java?

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I'm trying to match exact AdvanceJava keyword with the given inputText string but it executes both if and else condition,instead of I want only AdvanceJava keyword matched.

```
String inputText = ("iwanttoknowrelatedtoAdvancejava").toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");

String match = "java";
List keywordsList = new ArrayList<>();//where keywordsList{advance,core,programming} -> keywordlist fetch 
// from database 

Enumeration e = Collections.enumeration(keywordsList);
int size = keywordsList.size();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String s1 = (String) keywordsList.get(i);
        if (inputText.contains(s1) && inputText.contains(match)) {
            System.out.println("Yes we providing " + s1);
        } else if (!inputText.contains(s1) && inputText.contains(match)) {
            System.out.println("Yes we are working on java");
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: just add to your while a flag check and when you found the word to change the flag

Comment: I guess you have both `java` and `advancedjava` in the keyword list. So, you can solve it by using `(?<!advanced)java` instead of `java` pattern, or sort the keyword list by length descending, and once a match is found, break from the loop.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - KeywordList contains only "advance,core,programming" keywords in String s1 as shown in code and String match= "java" keyword is defined static, meanwhile I'm trying to check if my string inpuText contains both advance and java keywords than code from if condition executes fine but if my string inpuText is not contain advance keyword only contains java keyword than my else condition executes. But it's not working in this format. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sithum - Thanks but it executes both condition of if else in output.Please refer Screen shot which I attached here. [image: We want only if condition executes because our statement contains Advance Java thus only statement of If condition executes here by using the code which you provide it executes both statements of if else condition. Thanks]

I applied following logic and it works fine. please refer it , Thanks.

```
    String inputText = ("iwanttoknowrelatedtoAdvancejava").toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");
    String match = "java"; 
     List<String> keywordsList = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT QUESTIONARIES_RAISED FROM QUERIES").list();  // Fetch values from database (advance,core,programming)
    String uniqueKeyword=null;
    String commonKeyword= null;
    int size =keywordsList.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
               String s1 = (String) keywordsList.get(i);//get values one by one from list
    if(inputText.contains(match)){
    if(inputText.contains(s1) && inputText.contains(match)){
    Queries q1 = new Queries();
    q1.setQuestionariesRaised(s1); //set matched keyword to getter setter method
    keywordsList1=session.createQuery("from Queries sentence where questionariesRaised='"+q1.getQuestionariesRaised()+"'").list(); // based on matched keyword fetch according to matched keyword sentence which stored in database
    for(Queries ob  : keywordsList1){

    uniqueKeyword=  ob.getSentence().toString();// Store fetched sentence to on string variable
      }
    break;
    }else {
      commonKeyword= "java only"; 
         }
       }
     }}
  if(uniqueKeyword!= null){
   System.out.println("Yes we providing......................" + uniqueKeyword);        
  }else if(commonKeyword!= null){
   System.out.println("Yes we providing " + commonKeyword);
    }else{      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this by using pattern and matcher classes

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("java");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Print this");
    m.find();
```

If you want to find multiple matches in a line, you can call find() and group() repeatedly to extract them all.

Comment: Sorry,Mayank Sharma this code also executes both if and else condition in my case.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can achieve what you seek using pattern matching.

In the first example I have taken your input text as it is. This only improves your algorithm which has O(n^2) performance.

```
String inputText = ("iwanttoknowrelatedtoAdvancejava").toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");

        String match = "java";
        List<String> keywordsList = Arrays.asList("advance", "core", "programming");

        for (String keyword : keywordsList) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(keyword.concat(match));

            Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);
            //System.out.println(m.find());
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("Yes we are providing " + keyword.concat(match));
            }
        }
```

But we can improve this in to a better implementation. Here's a more generic version of the above implementation. This code doesn't manipulate the input text before matching, rather we provide a more generic regular expression which ignores spaces and matches case insensitive manner.

```
String inputText = "i want to know related to Advance java";

        String match = "java";
        List<String> keywordsList = Arrays.asList("advance", "core", "programming");

        for (String keyword : keywordsList) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(MessageFormat.format("(?i)({0}\\s*{1})", keyword, match));
            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(MessageFormat.format("(?i)({0})", match));

            Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);
            Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(inputText);
            //System.out.println(m.find());
            if(m.find()) {
                System.out.println("Yes we are providing " + keyword.concat(match));
            } else if(m1.find()) {
                System.out.println("Yes we are working with " + match);
            }
        }
```

Comment: sithum - Thanks but if only java is exist in my string instead of java than how to handle that using the same code by invoking the else condition?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on that requirement. Do you mean if the text is like "i want to know related to java" then it should be handled using an else condition?

Comment: sithum - Yup exactly.For that what should I have to implement in this same code ?
Thanks

Comment: dhruv_0707 sorry for the delayed response. I've updated the second example.

Comment: @sithum- no worries please refer screen shot and logic which I used for the same. thanks